# Правильно созтавить запрос

Tags: sql-server

```
Select postachalnik.Nazva, Tovar.Nazva, Tovar.NaSklade
FROM Tovar, postachalnik
WHERE Tovar.id_postav=1 AND NaSklade < 30;
```

Как правильно вывести перечень товаров определенного поставщика имеющихся в определенном количестве
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводит еще имена других постачальников, должен быть ПП Фриз.
Как правильно написать, чтобы искало по определенному ID

Comment: А где условия связывания?

Comment: забыл..........

Answer (score 3):

```
    Select postachalnik.Nazva,Tovar.Nazva, Tovar.NaSklade
FROM Tovar INNER JOIN postachalnik ON postachalnik.id_postach = Tovar.id_postav
WHERE Tovar.id_postav=1 AND NaSklade < 30;
```